# Flag a group of records with common field in table where they don't have fields in another field

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset like this, where 'Y' indicates the primary record for each reference id.

```
  SELECT * FROM groups;
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
| id | Name   | ReferenceID | IsReferenceRecord | GroupHasReferenceRecord |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Black  |           1 | NULL              | NULL                    |
|  2 | Red    |           1 | NULL              | NULL                    |
|  3 | Blue   |           1 | Y                 | NULL                    |
|  4 | Green  |           2 | NULL              | NULL                    |
|  5 | Orange |           2 | NULL              | NULL                    |
|  6 | Yellow |           2 | Y                 | NULL                    |
|  7 | Pink   |           3 | NULL              | NULL                    |
|  8 | White  |           3 | NULL              | NULL                    |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1198

As you can see, in some instances, there is no primary record indicated. I would like to run a query to highlight those rows.

Here's what I tried:

Comment: you would like to flag just pink and white in your examlpe? could you please provide your desired result?

Comment: @Panto thanks yes I did so on the fiddle but basically Pink and White would get the last field, GroupHasReferenceRecord set to 'N' and the rest would be set to 'Y' since Pink and White a) both have ReferenceID='3' and both/all of them have IsReferenceRecord=NULL

Comment: @strawberry I fixed table you are right, I used empty by accident, now NULL. #2 the sqlfiddle is the 'clear and simple' version, moved to the top on edit so it can be accessed first.

Comment: @Strawberry just added one here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1198

Comment: None of the given answers were correct? just to know if more effort is needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM groups x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN groups y 
             ON y.referenceid = x.referenceid 
            AND y.isreferencerecord = 'y' 
          WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
| id | Name  | ReferenceID | IsReferenceRecord | GroupHasReferenceRecord |
+----+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|  7 | Pink  |           3 | NULL              | NULL                    |
|  8 | White |           3 | NULL              | NULL                    |
+----+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1198/2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want all the original records of your table with a Y/N flag... if it's so, try this:

```
SELECT g1.id
      ,g1.Name
      ,g1.ReferenceID
      ,g1.IsReferenceRecord
      ,case when g1.Name = g2.Name then 'N' 
            else 'Y'
       end as GroupHasReferenceRecord
FROM Groups as g1
LEFT JOIN (select *
             from Groups
            where ReferenceId not in (select distinct ReferenceID
                                        from Groups
                                       where IsReferenceRecord = 'Y'
                                     )
          ) as g2
ON g1.Name=g2.Name
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1198/11